# How to make society ravaged by random killing, prosper and remain happy?

Tags: society, survival, psychology, medical

1. Set in near future.
2. Human population is at most a hundred thousand.
3. Everyone lives in mountainous regions to escape deadly miasma.
4. The air is infected by nanites which can cause cardiac arrest in humans.
5. All humans are being infected by nanites.
6. The nanites are all connected in a network and would not activate altogether at once.
7. Death in such a way is completely random and usually occurs at rate of a hundred per year.
8. People only have access to primitive technology and no Internet.
9. Food and water are scarce.
10. No sign of miasma retreating anytime soon.
11. Most importantly they are aware of the "curse".

Q: I need to find a way for the people to prosper and be happy, any solution?

Comment: 1/1000 doesn't even come close to the death rates human put up with prior to modern medicine, currently globally about 0.5 people die per 100 people every year, you have raised that yo 0.6/100, for comparison the modern day US has a death rate of about 0.8/100 so I doubt you will have any significant effect.

Comment: Mostly depend on age and sex of those 100k. And you need to add that extra 100 to regular people death. If you have birth-rate in minus (which is natural for cities of 100k) people won't be happy when they calculate that there are 600 more people dying than being born.

Comment: Under these circumstances families will just have more kids.  Modern day USA and Europe are anomalies in history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The principle of the Two-Edged-Sword.**

The nanites were created for a purpose, to cure disease, prevent the ravages of ageing, to heal minor wounds and eliminate cancer and autoimune conditions. Mental illness is unknown as any major imballance of neurotransmitters is regulated and stabilised. The nanites still do these things for the most part.

The problem comes when a faulty bit of code (meant to put people into a protective coma upon major-injury until they can recieve emergency treatment) kicks in periodically - people die.

People are healthy and permanently young and vigorous, we all die some day and there is nothing to be done, and being too busy with the business of survival to work themselves into a state of existential-angst - happiness is the natural condition.

Comment: Man u r good I wish I'm as smart as u hee hee.

Comment: The Stargate SG1 episode ‘Hundred days’ is very similar to this. The people grow to maturity quickly, and then have perfect health and happiness. Downside is they die at 100 days old.

Comment: @Joe Bloggs Ahh, so it is, I remember. Pelops wasn't it? The occasion T'lk showed Daniel that "Linear B" is an ancient dialect of Go'auld, and Jack got married by accident.

Comment: Agrajag: That’s the one. I’ve never trusted women offering me cakes since!

Comment: I really like this answer, but I'd like to offer a slight alternative.  Instead of death being a malfunction, perhaps the nanites are designed to keep a stable population of 100,000.  In the past, it did this by killing the genetically weak, but now, the population is so healthy that the "least fit" person alive when a new baby is born may be a completely normal healthy person.

Answer (score 2):

**It will not have any effect, certainly not compared to everything else**.

1/1000 doesn't even come close to the death rates human put up with prior to modern medicine, currently globally about 5 people die per 1000 people every year, you have raised that to 6/1000, for comparison the modern day USA has a death rate of about 8/1000 so I doubt you will have any significant effect.

Starvation will have a much bigger effect than your nanites anyway, current countries actually comes as high as 14-15 deaths per 1000, your extra 1/1000 would be a drop in bucket. It will certainly be noticeable to the populace but the impact it will have on their day to day lives will be insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

It's little different from past diseases.

In the past we had a lot of deaths from disease like dysentary, typhus, cholera, smallpox, measles, even certain types of the flu! Back then there was even less knowledge, and knowing or not knowing you are dying from HIV or cancer hasnt exactly improved matters much.

Your population simply doesnt know better. People live, people die of something. If they know it's because of nanites, big deal! Its like knowing its cancer that's killing you, nasty but what are you going to do about it? At least you wont be filled with chemicals that make you sick and your death would be relatively painless compared to all the other deadly diseases. They would be more worried about their version of the plague.

Comment: So are u betting just on human spirit? Would they be able to realise happiness even though they are haunted by the past, left with nothing at present and even the future seems all gloomy and hopeless?

Comment: Its not much different from, say, just after WWI. And despite the immense grief this war caused people still managed to find happiness. Ofcourse it did lay down the groundwork for immense crisis and the eventual WWII but simply being threatened by what is essentially a disease did not stop the human condition

Comment: @user6760 I'd say it's a solid bet.  Human civilizations have existed under far worse conditions for 10,000 years of history, and probably another 100,000 years of prehistory before that.  We haven't seen a civilization collapse over something this small yet!